# Save multiples lists data in one list

Tags: python, list

i have to save multiples lists data and their position in one or 2 lists if possible. I show you an example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8,9,10]
list3 = ["a","b","c"]
all_list = []
all_list.append(list1)
all_list.append(list2)
all_list.append(list3)
print(all_list)
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9,10],["a","b","c"]]
```

The problem is i can't get `list2[3]` from `all_list` for exemple. I will only get the whole list2( all_list[1] )
Anyone knows how i can get individual values back ?
I also tried to do:

```
all_list = list1+list2+list3
```

but i can't do that because i don't know the length of each list so it will get messy

Comment: why can you not get `list2[3]` ?? It does print `8`

Comment: You can: all_list[1][3]

Comment: thx  mmachine your solution works i didn't knows that i'm starting thx a lot

Comment: @luka If the solution works, do accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> all_list[1][3]
8
```

would do that for you

When you call `all_list[1]` you are calling the second sub-list inside the main list which is `all_list`. Then to call the 4th value inside that sublist you will have to again say `all_list[1][3]`

Answer (score 0):

To get the fourth element of second sublist , you can use -

```
all_list[1][3]
```

Demo (For your example) -

```
>>> all_list[1][3]
8
```